# Android: How to pass EditText's text property to DataBinding expression of another view

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have an EditText (`@+id/quantityNumber`) and a Button (`@+id/addToCartButton`) view next to each other in my layout. The EditText is a quantity field and the Button takes the value entered in the quantity field and executes a method within it's onClickListener. I'm trying to pass the value of the EditText view's "text" property to the DataBinding expression in the Button's `android:onClick` property like this:

`android:onClick="@{() -> productDetailViewModel.onAddButtonClicked(quantityNumber.getText())}`

per [this example.](https://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20clearOnFocusAndDispatch=%22@%7B()%20-%3E%20viewmodel.timePerWorkSetChanged(setWorkTime.getText())%7D%22)

or just by passing `quantityNumber.text`.

However I keep getting an error message:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import com.example.checkoutexample.databinding.FragmentProductDetailBindingImpl;
                                              ^
  symbol:   class FragmentProductDetailBindingImpl
  location: package com.example.checkoutexample.databinding
```

Here's the full code of the two views. Thank you so much for all your help!

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ProductDetailFragment">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="productDetailViewModel"
            type="com.example.checkoutexample.ProductDetailViewModel" />
    </data>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/productImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/cupcake"
                tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/productTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:text="@string/hazelnut_cupcakes"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/productPrice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_small"
                    android:text="@string/product_price"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/stockCountMessage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
                    android:textColor="@{productDetailViewModel.remainingStock == 0 ? @color/red : @color/blue}"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:text="@{productDetailViewModel.remainingStock == 0 ? @string/out_of_stock : @string/stock_msg(productDetailViewModel.remainingStock)}"
                    tools:text="(5 items left)" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/productDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:text="@string/product_description" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quantityLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:text="@string/quantity" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/quantityNumber"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_small"
                    android:ems="2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:minWidth="48dp"
                    android:minHeight="48dp"
                    android:text="@string/quantity_1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/addToCartButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_small"
                    android:enabled="@{productDetailViewModel.remainingStock == 0 ? false : true}"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> productDetailViewModel.onAddButtonClicked(quantityNumber.getText())}"
                    android:text="@string/add" />
            </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/checkoutButton"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_large"
            android:text="@{@string/checkout(productDetailViewModel.orderTotal)}"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</layout>
```

And here's the code for the Fragment:

```kotlin
class ProductDetailFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentProductDetailBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var viewModel: ProductDetailViewModel
    private var stockLeft = 0

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentProductDetailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[ProductDetailViewModel::class.java]

        binding.apply {
            productDetailViewModel = viewModel
            lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

            viewModel.orderTotal.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { orderTotal ->
                with(checkoutButton) {
                    setOnClickListener {
                        val action =
                            ProductDetailFragmentDirections.actionProductDetailFragmentToShoppingCartFragment(
                                orderTotal
                            )
                        view.findNavController().navigate(action)
                    }
                }
            }

            viewModel.insufficientStock.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { insufficientStock ->
                if (insufficientStock) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        getString(R.string.low_stock_error, viewModel.remainingStock.value),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
            }

            addToCartButton.setOnClickListener {
// Would like to replace these two lines with DataBinding
//                val orderQuantity = quantityNumber.text.toString().toInt()
//                viewModel.onAddButtonClicked(orderQuantity)

                hideKeyboard(view)
            }
        }

        return view
    }

    private fun hideKeyboard(view: View) {
        val inputMethodManager =
            activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: please post complete kotlin and xml code

Comment: @Maveňツ I added the full code above. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get it to work. Although it seems an overly complex approach and likely not best practice. If others have a better way of doing this I'm definitely interested in seeing your solution .

```xml
android:onClick="@{() -> productDetailViewModel.onAddButtonClicked(Integer.parseInt(quantityNumber.getText().toString()))}"
```

The reason why this works is because the `onAddButtonClicked()` method from the ViewModel requires an `Int` type for the argument passed to it. Because of this I needed to convert the value I was getting from the `quantityNumber` view from an "EditText" to a "string" to finally an "Int".

Hope this helps others.